# Typescript injecting `require(...)` instead of importing files

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to compile a third party module [`pdfassembler`](https://github.com/DevelopingMagic/pdfassembler) to include the source of `import`s that are currently referenced by `require` statements in the compiled result.

The `src/pdfassember.ts` file has e.g.

```
import { PDFDocument } from 'pdfjs-dist/lib/core/document';
```

which instead of being imported is converted into

```
require('/Users/.../pdfassembler/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/lib/core/document.js')
```

... instead of the source code.

Running `tsc --traceModules` gives e.g.

> ======== Module name 'pdfjs-dist/lib/core/document' was successfully resolved to '/Users/bmh/Repos/pdfassembler/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/lib/core/document.js'. ========

It's not clear how to have the imports included.  The Typescript documentation [on module resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) offers no indication of why this might be happening. (And at the time of writing typescriptlang.org is down)

I expect this is a species of the problem of ["import vs require"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions), but the answer there offers did not point to any apparent solutions.

The import PDF.js has an `@types/pdfjs-dist`, and it occurred to me that this may be usable, but it's not clear how.

An ideal answer would indicate how to compile pdfassembler without any `require` statements, but it'd be useful to know generally what Typescript is doing/expecting and how to work around this sort of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to combine multiple modules into one file, you'll need to use a module bundler such as Webpack, Rollup, or Browserify.  Module bundling is beyond the scope of the TypeScript compiler.  (The only purpose of TypeScript's module resolution functionality is to support type checking and code navigation in IDEs.)